# Inviting friends to a Facebook event works, but returns an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the graph api explorer I create an event

```
100004981634237/events?name=testEventz&start_time=2013-06-27T00:00:11-0700
```

then I invite some friends to the event:

```
533485663360781/invited?users=6025656,100002049936997
```

Facebook returns this error:

```
   "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
```

But the events invitations are actually sent...

Is this a bug with Facebook? If not how can I get it to return true